# How can I do this matrix operation?

Tags: c

The # operation between matrices can be defined as follows:

Matrix A: dimension m x n, matrix B: dimension p x q, matrix A # B: dimension mp x nq.

[image]

It is output that I got.

```
0
0
0
0
```

My codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int multiply(int s);

int row[2][2]={1,-3,-5,-7};
int row2[3][2]={0,2,4,6,8,0};

int main(void) {
    int result,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){       
            result=multiply(row[i][j]);
            printf("%d\n",result);
        }
    }
    

    return 0;
}
    
int multiply(int number){
    int result,i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<2;j++){       
            result=row2[i][j]*(number);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `multiply`, you return unconditionally from the innermost loop. That's probably not what you want. Also, don't you need an `int result[6][4]` metrix somewhere?

Comment: Why are you using global variables?

Comment: If I manage to get results from the program, I can do what you say. Now I only get 0 output from the program.@M Oehm

Comment: `row2[0][0]` is `0`. Your `multiply` behave as if it were `int multiply(int number){ return 0 * number; }`. You have to consider whether you want to just print the resulting values or to use `multiply` to store those in a bigger matrix and then print it. In either case, you have to substantially modify both `main` and `multiply`.

Comment: I want to create a new big matrix, but how do I do this I still haven't figured it out.@Bob__

Comment: Well, "how to do" largely depends on what you have learned so far and what compiler/standard are you allowed to use (that `#include <conio.h>` concerns me a lot). Are you supposed to use dynamic allocation or just statically sized arrays? Have you been introduced to structs? Is your compiler at least C99 standard compliant?

Comment: Will my use of structures help me? What did you mean by dynamic and static string? And I'm using dev c. @ Bob__

Answer (score 0):

The original code you posted has several problems:

1. multiply() doesn't return a value on all paths.
2. You exit multiply prematurely the moment you complete the first pass of the inner loop, instead of waiting for *all* the results.
3. You don't accumulate "result" in your loops
4. You don't initialize "number before you try to use it; nor do pass "number" as a parameter to "multiple()".
5. Per your latest update, you don't even want an int "result" ... you want a *matrix*: `int[6][4] results`.

Consider something like this instead:

```
void multiply(int ma[2][2], int mb[3][2], int result[6][4]){
    int i, j, k;
    //
    for(i=0;i<...;i++){
        ...
        for(j=0;j<...;j++){       
            ...
            for(k=0;k<...;k++){       
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv{}) {
    int row[2][2]={1,-3,-5,-7};
    int row2[3][2]={0,2,4,6,8,0};
    int results[6][4] = {
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0}
   };
    ...
    multiply(row, row2, results);
    ...
}
```

### Note

This code is not complete.  That's for *you* to figure out.  In no small part, by familiarizing yourself with your debugger (gdb?) and single-stepping through the code.

Comment: Doesn't this code get me a single printout?
I want all results like in the last matrix. @paulsm4

Comment: We're not going to write your code for you. Your function returned a single result, your variable can only hold a single value, so I tried to show you some of what you were doing wrong so far. If you want the results in a matrix ... then you need to declare a matrix! I've updated my reply. Please post back if you have any questions.  Please post any code changes you've made.  And *PLEASE* confirm that you're comfortable using the debugger, as-needed.